# DIV padding interfering with width

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 100% width and some padding.
The div is larger than it's wrapper.
Obviously I don't want that to happen.
I can not work with pixels on the width as the width is dynamic.

I've tried out various CSS tricks and searched through stackoverflow. I can not imagine how nobody asked about this probably simple problem yet, but I really found nothing that works so far. That said, please excuse me if this might still be a duplicate question.

```css
.entryrow {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background: linear-gradient(#2c647b,#191654);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;background:black;height:120px;">
  <div class="entryrow">
    Blubb
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, use box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: @FatihErol - he already uses it, see the code.

Comment: @Chris S. i would suggest to move the padding to the parent instead of the margin on the child.

Comment: _“The div is larger than it's wrapper.”_ - no, it is not. But it has to move around of course inside the parent, due to the _margin_ you added.

Comment: CBroe is right. Your div is not larger than its wrapper, the issue is caused by its margins. You should remove its margins and add those values to its parent's paddings instead.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Setting width to auto and display to block as answered below did the job perfect and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep the element a block element and you won't need `width:100%` or `box-sizing:border-box`  (by the way it's good to keep it to avoid any future issue related to padding/border combined with width)

```css
.entryrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(#2c647b, #191654);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:black;overflow:hidden">
  <div class="entryrow">
    Blubb
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, there are many helpful responses and I've learned new about the calc function but this solution seems more clean so I've accepted this one as the most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `calc(100% - 10px);` for width (= 100% minus 2 x 5px margins) (borders don't count since you use `box-sizing: border-box`)

```css
.entryrow {
 position:relative;
 width:calc(100% - 10px);
 height:100px;
 background: linear-gradient(#2c647b,#191654);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;background:black;height:120px;">
  <div class="entryrow">
    Blubb
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `calc()` function of css on your `.entryrow`.

```css
.entryrow {
 position:relative;
 width:calc(100% - 10px); /* 10px for the margin applied below */
 height:100px;
 background: linear-gradient(#2c647b,#191654);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;background:black;height:400px;">
  <div class="entryrow">
    Blubb
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, less code, is more ;)

**EDIT**: To demonstrate that creating multiple rows with this solution, would result the expected result by the OP, most of the other answers would still have aligning issues.

For example, the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51928740/572771) if you add more than one row, it will cut off the top and bottom of the rows.

```css
.wrapper {
  background:black;
  padding: 1%
}
.entryrow {
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(#2c647b,#191654);
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="entryrow">
    Blubb1
  </div>
  <div class="entryrow">
    Blubb1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but would you kindly explain why exactly you changed the padding to percentage?

Comment: `I can not work with pixels on the width as the width is dynamic.` so i figured to make it as dynamic as possible.
It should work if you change them back to pixels.

Comment: the accepted solution asnwer the question and the specific issue ;) it's not about alignement or adding more rows, it's about width and margin/padding issue. If we want more row we simply remove the fixed height. No need to add comment about other answers ;) simply describe what you answer is doing

Comment: I did explain what my solution is doing and gave an example why another answer would not work. You are taking things personally, while i could have gave an example of any other answer, i just offered a solution for other visitors that will visit this page.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Now that you edited your answer and removed the fixed height, yes, it would result the same as my answer.

Comment: not the same, you are using % values which is not accurate .. resize the browser and see the effect, it's not a good idea to have margin/padding like this, you will have different rendring across devices

Comment: Its called `RESPONSIVE`, anyway, im out of this conversation.

Answer (score -1):

If you give a `max-width: 100px;` to your wrapping div and `max-width: 90px;` to your `.entyrow` it is working perfectly. Obviously, you just say to the divs `width: 100%;` but if both of them 100% you don't have space for the padding. It's up to you what px you put in the max-width. Hope it helped.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why people who want to help get instant minus reputation. Thank you for trying to help me. However I found @TemaniAfif 's response the most helpful tbh.